# Mac opperating system software

Tags: appleworks

So my all in one apple pc has been wiped completely clean no os or nothing what can I download and then transfer via USB

Comment: Boot into recovery and reinstall from there.

Comment: Do you know what soft ware I can use or download.

Comment: Did you try to boot into recovery mode?

Comment: See the question linked on top, the answer there covers basically all cases.